# Angular - adding files to .gitignore

Tags: git, angular, twilio

Trying to learn how to use Twilio with Angular app. First thing we need to do is to set Twilio credentials and add that file to `.gitignore`, but I see in this [link (example Angular-Twilio project in github)](https://github.com/SimpleVictor/twilio-angular2) that `.env` was not been added, or was it?

`.env` :

```
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=SECRET
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=SECRET
TWILIO_NUMBER=SECRET
```

`.gitignore` :

```
node_modules
.idea
typings
server/**/*.js
server/**/*.js.map
client/**/*.js
client/**/*.js.map
/npm-debug.log
```

So I guess I should add `.env` anywhere in `.gitignore` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you should, your tokens should be kept private, remove them from the answer aswell if they were not an example.

Comment: These creds from example :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes you should definitely add `.env` to `.gitignore` else anybody can easily use your credentials for their benefit and 
you will be paying their bills !!

```
node_modules
.idea
typings
server/**/*.js
server/**/*.js.map
client/**/*.js
client/**/*.js.map
/npm-debug.log
.env
```